# Inserting in local DB using Room doesn't work - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, android-room

When I fetch data from API (which works), I want to insert it into DB, which for some reason it doesn't work. I'm using Room library. (With Koin library for DI)

Here is my code:

Service for fetching data from API:

```
class PlayerServiceImplFb : PlayerService {

override fun fetchAllPlayers(): Observable<List<PlayerFb>> {
    return Observable.create<List<PlayerFb>> {
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/players")
        val matchList : MutableList<PlayerFb> = mutableListOf()
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val children = snapshot.children
                children.forEach {
                    Log.d("PlayerServiceImpl", "Added player ${it.getValue(PlayerFb::class.java)} to list")
                    matchList.add(it.getValue(PlayerFb::class.java)!!)
                }
                it.onNext(matchList)
                it.onComplete()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

}

DAO:

```
@Dao
abstract class PlayerDao {

//DELETE ALL AND INSERT PLAYERS
@Transaction
open fun deleteAndInsertAll(entities: List<PlayerEntity>) {
    deleteAll()
    insertAll(entities).blockingAwait()
}

@Insert( onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE )
abstract fun insertAll(entities: List<PlayerEntity>): Completable

@Query("DELETE FROM players")
abstract fun deleteAll()

//GET ALL PLAYERS
@Query("SELECT * FROM players")
abstract fun getAll(): Observable<List<PlayerEntity>>
}
```

Repository (uses service and dao above via Koin DI):

```
class PlayerRepoImpl (
private val remoteDataSource: PlayerService,
private val localDataSource: PlayerDao
): PlayerRepo {

override fun fetchAllPlayers(): Observable<List<PlayerUI>> {
    return remoteDataSource
        .fetchAllPlayers()
        .doOnNext {
            it.forEach {
                Log.d("PlayerRepoImpl", it.username)
            }
            Log.d("PlayerRepoImpl","Pokusaj upisa u bazu")
            val entities = it.map {
                PlayerEntity (
                    it.id,
                    it.username,
                    it.email,
                    it.profileImage,
                    it.universes
                )
            }
localDataSource.deleteAndInsertAll(entities)
        }
        .map {
            //koristi Resource ovde
            it.map {
                PlayerUI(it.id, it.username, it.email, it.profileImage, it.universes)
            }
        }
}
}
```

ViewModel layer:

```
class PlayerViewModel (
private val playerRepo: PlayerRepo
) : ViewModel(), PlayerContract.ViewModel {

private val subscriptions = CompositeDisposable()

override val playerStates: MutableLiveData<PlayerState> = MutableLiveData()

override fun fetchAllPlayers() {
    val subscription = playerRepo
        .fetchAllPlayers()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            {
                Log.d("PlayerViewModel", "Fetched all players from firebase")
                it.forEach {
                    Log.d("PlayerViewModel", it.username)
                }
                playerStates.value = PlayerState.Success(it)
            },
            {
                Log.d("PlayerViewModel", "error")
            }
        )
    subscriptions.add(subscription)
}
}
```

Everytime I get second error lambda: "PlayerViewModel", "error" printed out. But if I comment out
localDataSource.deleteAndInsertAll(entities) in Repository, it works fine.
Lost so much time on this... Im desperate. Thank you.

Database model:

```
@Entity(tableName = "players")
data class PlayerEntity (
    @PrimaryKey val id: String,
    val username: String,
    val email: String,
    val profileImage: String,
    val universes: List<String>
)
```

API response model:

```
data class PlayerFb (
    val id: String, //kopka me da li mi treba
    val username: String,
    val email: String, //kopka me da li mi treba
    val profileImage: String,
    val universes: List<String>
) {
    constructor() : this("", "", "", "", listOf())
}
```

Comment: I would recommend trying to make deleteAndInsertAll and deleteAll functions return completable as well, maybe that would work

Comment: Nice try, but its something else. Thanks anyway